# IDA can't load DLL, possibly packed but how?

Tags: ida, disassembly, dll, unpacking

I tried to load a DLL to reverse engineer the code inside using IDA, but it tells me this on loading:

[image]

So i assume the .text resource is somewhat "packed". I then fetched a tool named ["DIE - Detect It Easy"](https://github.com/horsicq/Detect-It-Easy) which should give me some insights of the DLL. It shows me this:

[image]

And for me it does not look like packed, or at least the tool can't detect any packing algorithm.

How can i proceed from here to get the DLL in a disassemble-able form?

Comment: it's just a warning (note the word *MAY*). How does the code actually look like after loading?